# can't use java file in same directory unless making an object

Tags: java

so i'm trying to use a file  Euclid.java alongside its driver EuclidDriver.java. if trying to call on a method in Euclid, the driver gives an error that it couldn't find the method. if i change up Euclid and make it an object, the driver can now use its methods. I don't understand how it cant find the method in the same directory but is able to make an object with that file. i have the Euclid class:

```
public class Euclid
{
   public static int gcd(int num1, int num2)
   {
      if(num2<=num1 && (num1%num2==0))
      {
         return num2;
      }
      else if(num1<num2)
      {
         return gcd(num2,num1);
      }
      else
      {
         return gcd(num2,num1%num2);
      }
   }
}
```

and the driver class:

```
public class EuclidDriver
{   
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {      
      int gcd = gcd(18,6);
      System.out.println(gcd);   
   }
   
}
```

Comment: If you want to use a method from another class you have to *instantiate* it. If you want to use methods from another class without instancing it, you can make the method static and call ClassName.method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must refer to Euclid class when you call the method.

Make the following changes in the driver class:

`int gcd = Euclid.gcd(18,6);`

So the class will be:

```
public class EuclidDriver
{   
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {      
      int gcd = Euclid.gcd(18,6);
      System.out.println(gcd);   
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a static method that you made in `Euclid`. Call static methods like this:

`Euclid.gcd(18, 6);`

You may need to import the class as well if it resides in another package.
Also a static import can be considered.